# Java How to show timer via Server?

Tags: java, server

I would like to use a timer that counts up like: 00:00:00 -> 00:00:01 and so on , I tried it with

```
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

but didn't worked. This is how i get my data from my localhost. I would like to use this to calculate the timer via my Server , but it doesnt work.
I just would like to see a timer alongside my uploaded file in my client GUI

Hope someone can help, if you have more questions ask me :)

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(format("http://localhost:8080/file/upload?uid={0}&time={1}", uid , time)
```

EDIT: [This is how my Client JTable looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWEDo.png) Its not my idea but my supervisor just want to see what the average time is that the server needs to run the (.bat) File. And u cant calc how long a (.bat) file needs so i need a timer that counts up.
And i was thinking this should be possible via the server.

Comment: If you're uploading a file, the client should actually hold the information about the connection speed and filesize as well. There is no sense in calculating the estimated upload time (which is what I guess you want to achieve?) on the server. If you really were on to just display a timer, do it ín the client as well. Don't calculate this on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into details if it is smart to do a server-side timer for uploads, you can't make a second-step with this

```
Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
```

because it will just execute at whatever speed your system is running at.
Something like the code below will trigger once every second, but you'll have to run that in its own thread as not to block the main-thread with the `while`:

```
while(true){
   System.out.printLine("tick");
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```